# Get value of radio button + Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, radio-button, zend-form

i have an element of type radio in my class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form

```
      $this->setMethod('post');    
      $this->setName("User type"); 
      $this->addElement('radio', 'User_type', array(
         'label' => 'User type:',
         'multioptions' => array(
        1 => 'Owner',
        2 => 'StandardUser',
        3 => 'BusinessdUser', ),
              ));
```

how can i get the value of the radio button ?
I tried with this code in my controller but it doesn't work

```
$form = new Application_Form_Login();
     if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $values = $form->getValues();
            var_dump($values['User_type']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you do have a submit button of some type correct? Also what is your action set to?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "doesn't work"? That's not a lot to go on. What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
$form = new Application_Form_Login();
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
        $value = $form->getValue('User_type');
        var_dump($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try :

```
    public function yourAction() {
        $form = new SomeForm();
        if($this->getRequest->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest->getPost();
            if($form->isValid($data)) {
                $rate = $_POST['your_radio_button'];
                // another code..
            }
        }
    }
```